# Can't click on ajax link VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I try to execute click event but it doesn't work. Anyone can help?

This is my code:

```
Sub resetValue()

Set Browser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

'Navigate to website address

If Browser.Visible = True Then 
    Browser.Visible = False
    Browser.navigate "http://stockprice.vn/a/statistics.html"

'Loop until browser in already state

While Browser.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Wend

'Reset the calculation info of page * 1000 by click Setting

Browser.document.getElementById("button-1024-btnInnerEl").Click
```

......

Thank you.

Comment: What does not work ? Any error message ?

Comment: when you click on this button an popup menu will appear, but i cannot make it work :), no error message

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks not good. `browser`is not declared; The `if` has no `end if`, `READYSTATE_COMPLETE`is unknown, `sub` has no `end sub`.

I assume you get an error from the VBA environment.

As a first approach, try this:

```
Sub resetValue()

    Dim browser

    Set browser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    'Navigate to website address

    If browser.Visible = True Then
        browser.Visible = False
    End If


    browser.navigate "http://stockprice.vn/a/statistics.html"

    'Loop until browser in ready state

    While browser.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend

    'Reset the calculation info of page * 1000 by click Setting

    browser.document.getElementById("button-1024-btnInnerEl").Click


End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I just copy a small sub in my program so it missing something, the browser variable declared in public variable. Can you help me to find out how to trigger click event for this button?